# Send GCM Push Notification to Multiple Token Id from nodeJs Server

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-messaging

I am using node-gcm-service package to send message from my server to the registered devices. When there is one device, the message is successfully delivered, when there are two devices, only the first device (deviceIds[0]) receives the message.

Does any one suggest me how to send notification from multiple device.

Comment: Not sure this is a duplicate. The other question is about the GCM API, whereas this question is about node-gcm.

Comment: how does your code look? what have you tried?